# I have a problem with "team" codeforces task, don't understand why my c++ code does work and doesn't

Tags: c++, matrix

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;   // number of problems
    int solvableProblems = 0;
    char matrix[n][3];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }   
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (j == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count >= 2) {
            solvableProblems++;
        }   
    }

    cout << solvableProblems;


return 0;
}
```

The task name is "team" on codeforces, looks like an easy problem, but my code does not work on the fifth test. we need to find how many tasks can a group of people solve(if there're 2 or more digits of 1 then, they can solve it, if less, then they can't. the input is:

```
5
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 0 1
0 0 0
```

and an output should be 1(cause there is only one row with more than 2 digits of one, but it gives me 4, if i'm not mistaken. can't find bug, can you help me?

Comment: `if (j == 1) { count++; }` doesn't look right. Did you mean `if (matrix[i][j] == 1)`?

Comment: it might be a problem with count variable, i tried to declare it in the beginning of the second for loop, but it didn't help

Comment: I don't even understand what the algorithm is supposed to do. Could you explain it better?

Comment: hm, you might be right, i'll try to recode it like you said

Comment: @ShaneWalsh That is also an issue. You need to reset `count = 0` for each row.

Comment: yes, you need to count how many rows are there which have 2 or more digits of 1 in it.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp it doesn't work

Comment: it outputs 0 every time

Comment: I just noticed, you are using a `char` matrix, not `int`, so the comparison should be `if (matrix[i][j] == '1')`

Comment: @Johnny Mopp THANKS!! man you are the best. it works now

Comment: `char matrix[n][3];` is [not legal C++ code](https://godbolt.org/z/odvqfM). Don't use poorly documented, poorly understood compiler extensions.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I worry that being aware of that being a compiler specific extension is the issue, not chosing to ignore that....

Comment: @Yunnosch I think the problem is that code competition sites choose to run compilers in non-compliant mode. It should be prohibited by law.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are checking whether j is equals to 1 rather than checking whether the value in the input is equal to 1. Change `if(j == 1)` with `if(matrix[i][j] == 1)`. Also, you need to set `count = 0` inside the outer for loop (after the `if(count >= 2)` block), otherwise your count will keep on increasing.

Edit:
As pointed out by Johnny Mopp, you have used `char` matrix instead of int. Now understand that chars are stored in C/C++ as their ASCII value, which means `(char)1` is stored as 49. You can solve this by two ways:

1. declare the matrix as `int`. This will result in input being stored as 1 and hence the comparison will result in an increment of count.
2. Without changing the declaration, compare using `if(matrix[i][j] == '1')`. This results in char 1 being compared to char 1, i.e., 49 equals 49. Again, your count will increment.

Comment: i really don't understand why

Comment: could  you please edit my code, maybe i do something wrong

Comment: i mean, it outputs 0 every time

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in Python 3 ([Answer accepted by Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/231/110824560))

```
n = int(input())
x=0
for i in range(n):
    p, v, t = input().split()
    p, v, t = [int(p), int(v), int(t)]
    if (p+v+t)>1:
        x+=1
print(x)
```

Just see the algorithm as I have done it in Python not in C++.